# Does IOS support Active Directory in any way?

Tags: ios, ipad, active-directory

I know this a pretty general question and I'm not looking for code or anything.  Even a link or short explanation would be nice..  Specifically searching for a way to browse network based active directories from an internal IOS application.  Using a cloud or email is not an option.. Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [recent article on IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-iphoneapp/index.html?ca=drs-) that explains how to use *OpenLDAP client libraries* in the iOS environment. You can use OpenLDAP client libraries to access LDAP sources, including Active Directory. Not all Active Directory operations are supported, but even basic queries should be sufficient for building a browsing application.

Comment: thanks.. this is going to make form some interesting reading.  Would've thought that apple would be at the forefront of integration into the enterprise environment.

Comment: @DJPlayer I am sure that if AD could run on OS X, it would deserve a lot more attention from Apple. As things currently stand, though, integrating with AD does not fit with Apple's vision of the world very well. I mean the "OS X runs on every desktop, and iOS runs on every smartphone" part of the vision :):):)

Comment: The author of this IBM article has everything on github along with a demo app in the examples dir:

https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts

Answer (score 0):

There is a recently released free solution called Centrify Express for Mobile that allows an iOS device (iPad/iPhone/iPod) to join Active Directory, so you can use AD to manage/secure the iOS device.