# Connect to Active Directory from iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, active-directory

I need to connect to an Active Directory from an iOS application. We cannot replicate or create a PHP/ASP wrapper for the AD because it is behind a VPN. The iPhone user must first connect to the VPN before he can use the application.

Can't seem to find anything other then `OpenLDAP` library for iOS. Since Active Directory uses it's own `LDAP` version, i think i cannot use `OpenLDAP`.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567676/does-ios-support-active-directory-in-any-way

The demo app linked may be of some help.

Comment: AD is LDAP. I've used perl LDAP modules to read AD data.  Have you tried the OpenLDAP library?

Comment: My app works fine with Windows Authentication through VPN without any OpenLDAP. Isn't Active Directory and Windows Authentication the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the VPN either by built-in **iOS VPN connection** or using **cisco anyconnect** ios free App.

Once connected you are now part of the internal network and you can hit the AD and any other device connected to this network.