# Connect to Active Directory from Android application

Tags: android, active-directory

I need to connect to Active Directory from Android application. I woudn't like to create Active Directory wrapper - web service or something like that for this task. Are there any standard libraries for that?

Question looks similiar to [Connect to Active Directory from iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238066/connect-to-active-directory-from-ios-application)  except operating system.